# Program for capturing iphone screen during video games execution

Tags: iphone, video-capture

I was wondering how it is possible to capture what's shown in the iphone screen while playing a video game.

I know that this can be done and that there have to be special programs for this since there are many sites out there that present a video review of iphone games.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

My [DisplayRecorder](http://rpetri.ch/cydia/displayrecorder/) does just this. It requires you to jailbreak.